# Not able to change frame-rate for input video using cv2.VideoCapture(video_path).set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, new_frame_rate)

Tags: python, python-3.6, frame-rate, opencv

I am reading a `.mp4` video file using opencv-python (3.4.3.18) and python (3.6.6)

```
vid = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)
```

The original video has around 59 FPS and I want to reduce it to 10 FPS. So, I set the `cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS` property using the following,

```
flag = vid.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 10)
```

(Ref: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.3/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#a8c6d8c2d37505b5ca61ffd4bb54e9a7c)

However, when I print the `flag` value it gives `False`. Which means the property is not supported by backend used by the `VideoCapture` instance. Hence, when I'm reading the frame using,

```
return_value, frame = vid.read()
```

it returns all the 59 frames making the post processing steps more time consuming. How to solve this issue?

Comment: Setting `VideoCapture` frame rate when reading from a file is meaningless -- you will always receive the frames as fast as the decoder can decode them. It's only relevant when reading from a camera.

Comment: Also, what exactly do you envision reducing the frame rate would do? Based on the text at the bottom of your question, it seems you expect it to skip frames?

Comment: Yes, I want to skip frames. I'm feeding these frames to YOLO object detection algorithm. If I don't skip frames then the detection runs through each and every frame which is not needed...

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I am having the same problem with Yolo

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried to change *cv2.waitKey()*?

For example: if you have a 60fps video,  try to use *cv2.waitKey(6000)*